# :hover effect on object out of Div (CSS/JS?)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a CSS hover effect that cycles between two images when you hover over the initial image.

HTML:

```
<img class="bottom" src="photos/800_800_<?php echo $r->image1;?>" />
<img class="top" src="photos/800_800_<?php echo $r->image2;?>" />
```

CSS:

```
#cf img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

How can I make it so that when you hover over a  tag that isn't in the div with the ID of #cf it triggers the same effect?

Comment: so could you show the actual markup with the element that should act as the trigger please?

Comment: Whare is js?  You add javascript tag.

Comment: Create a [MCVE] please

Answer (score 0):

You are not add style id you must add id in img tag try following code.

```
<img id="cf" class="bottom" src="photos/800_800_<?php echo $r->image1;?>" />
```